# $\sqrt{x^2-1} =\sqrt{x+1}\cdot\sqrt{x-1}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:** The equation $$\sqrt{x^2-1} =\sqrt{x+1}\cdot\sqrt{x-1},$$

holds true:

a) $\forall \ x\in\mathbb{R}$

b) $\forall \ x\in\{\mathbb{R}:|x|\geq1\}$

c) $\forall \ x\in\{\mathbb{R}:x\geq1\}$

d) None of the above.

---

**Reasoning:**

Using $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$ I get that $$\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)}=\sqrt{(x+1)}\cdot\sqrt{(x-1)}.$$

This means that $$\sqrt{x^2-1}\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{(x+1)}\cdot\sqrt{(x-1)}.$$ Thus, this should be true for all reals, for example $x=0$ one would obtain $$\begin{array}{lcl}
\text{LHS}  & = & \sqrt{0^2-1} = \sqrt{-1} = i.\\
\text{RHS}  & = & \sqrt{0+1}\cdot \sqrt{0-1} = \sqrt{1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=1\cdot(-1)=i. \\
\end{array} $$

The answer is c). However, if you ask me, it's true that everything becomes undefined (complex, if you will) once we go under $x=1$ but the question asks for which real values of $x$ the equation holds. Clearly the equation holds for $x<1$ as well.

If you disagree with me, please state why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I disagree with you purely on the basis that $\sqrt{-1}$ is either $i$ or $-i$, and you have no idea of knowing whether the left-hand side and the right-hand side chooses the same one.

Comment: Hint:  How about if $x < 0$?  (For example, $x = -2$.)

Comment: In general, the formula
$$\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$
breaks down when $a < 0$ and $b < 0$.

Comment: Let $x=-2$. Then $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{3}$, but $\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-3}=-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Damn! You guys are right...how could I look past such a trivial thing... I always get a pathetic "ofcourse"-moment once you guys point it out for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Who said you can "take a minus sign out of the root"?

Comment: @Dror - What do you mean?

Comment: You can't toy around with negative numbers in a square root, and can't merge it with others, if you happen to write it like that in the first place. Do your self a favor and think of $i$ as $i^2 = -1$. $\sqrt{-1}$ is what it is as a whole and you can't touch it, if you must write it.

Comment: @Dror - Thank you. I will think as you suggested to avoid any future screwup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so this has an answer: Algebraic identities (like legal contracts) come with stipulations that must be met if the conclusions are to be true.

In the real setting, the bare equation $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a\vphantom{b}}\sqrt{b}$ is not an "identity" at all. The correct statement is
$$
\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a\vphantom{b}}\sqrt{b}\quad\text{for all real $a \geq 0$, $b \geq 0$.}
$$

The [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) "for all real $a \geq 0$, $b \geq 0$" is not a decorative flourish, but *an essential part of the identity*.

Here, consequently, the stated algebraic relationship holds if and only if $x + 1 \geq 0$ and $x - 1 \geq 0$, i.e., if and only if $x \geq 1$.

---

The deeper point is, if as a student you find yourself memorizing fragments such as
$$
a^{2} - b^{2} = (a - b)(a + b)\quad\text{or}\quad
0 \leq x^{2},
$$
or even worse,
$$
y = mx + b\quad\text{or}\quad
a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}\quad\text{or}\quad
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a},
$$
you need to shift the focus of your attention: The meaning of symbols matters.

Comment: Wouldn't "the correct statement" be $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{|a|}\sqrt{|b|}$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I'd prefer to think of your equation as _a_ correct statement (for all real $a$ and $b$). The proximate point is, I omitted the absolute values following OP's reasoning, and because the motivating question doesn't have any. :)

Comment: But that what it's all about: the equation is true iff $x^2-1\geq0$ and $x+1$ and $x-1$ are both non-negative.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Yes, but since the arguments are non-negative, there's no need for explicit absolute value signs. (In other words, it's true that $\sqrt{|x^{2} - 1|} = \sqrt{|x + 1|} \sqrt{|x - 1|}$ for all real $x$, but that's not relevant to OP's question.)